# Curve of a circle?

Tags: geogebra

AB are two points on a circle.
When inserting text into Geogebra, I use LaTex and don't have an option to assign a curve sign above AB

Answer (score 1):

like this using math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\begin{document}
$\wideparen{abc}$
$\wideparen{AB}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

And another way using tikz :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node[name=orig, inner sep=0mm] {abc};
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw (orig.north west)
to[out=45,in=135] (orig.north east);
\qquad
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \node[name=orig, inner sep=0mm] {AB};
\tikz[overlay, remember picture] \draw (orig.north west)
to[out=45,in=135] (orig.north east);
\end{document}
```

[image]